# Use of prevState to change value in array of objects does not return expected value

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state

I am using the following method to try to change the value of task.isComplete to !task.isComplete onClick.

```js
handleComplete = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState(
    (prevState) => ({
      listOfTasks: prevState.listOfTasks.map((task) => {
        if (task.id === event.target.id) {
          task.isComplete = !task.isComplete;
          console.log(task);
        }
        return task;
      }),
    }),
    () => console.log(this.state.listOfTasks)
  );
};
```

when clicking the button the 2 logs are:

```
{nameOfTask: "aaaa", isComplete: true, id: "1610746018062"}

TodoListTest.js:54 
[{…}]
0: {nameOfTask: "aaaa", isComplete: false, id: "1610746018062"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

React seems to only consider the second log state so I don't get the expected change, incomplete turning to true at the end of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a shallow copy of the `task` object to update its `isComplete` property.

```js
  handleComplete = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        listOfTasks: prevState.listOfTasks.map((task) => {
          if (task.id === event.target.id) {
            return {
              ...task,
              isComplete: !task.isComplete
            };
          }
          return task;
        })
      }),
      () => console.log(this.state.listOfTasks)
    );
  };
```